# Found a hidden php FILE/(CODE) in WordPress ROOT. Is this a Backdoor? Should I delete it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a hidden PHP file in my WordPress ROOT. Can someone please confirm if its a Backdoor and I should delete it or is this file safe?

The file name is:

```
.wysiwygPro_preview_2cc37e731786ff9b24157cd9f049b9cb.php
```

And its contet:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['randomId'] != "h6wErVoQiTtcfJOQAXxRY56_1NdgoGfVy_NpD4ecgtbBjp6URh8lF") {
    echo "Access Denied";
    exit();
}

 display the HTML code:
echo stripslashes($_POST['wproPreviewHTML']);

?>
```

Can someone please tell me if its dangerous to have such code on server or its safe?
Thank you for your comments and thoughts on this code :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above reply, I'd say it's not.

If the user doesn't know the filepath or doesn't enter a correct randomId, that's it.

BUT, if that person knows the randomId (hi there) they can $_POST to '.wysiwygPro_preview_2cc37e731786ff9b24157cd9f049b9cb.php' with 'wproPreviewHTML' and make content appear as if it was from your URL. To an extent. They named the file well.

And if that's true I can only imagine a legit looking log-in form with a malicious submit URL.

Comment: If server is setup correctly, dot files can't be accessed from outside, otherwise it's true.

Answer (score 0):

It's a file generated by the wysiwyg editor in your cPanel hosting - it's not a hack or a backdoor.

They're perfectly safe to delete if you want to free up space.